# Transaction aborted Error when creating publication using core service.How to resolve this error and what the reason of this error?

Tags: 2013, core-service

This is my code

```
String publicationName="WebSite";

PublicationData publicationData=(PublicationData)client.getDefaultData(ItemType.PUBLICATION,"tcm:0",new ReadOptions());

 publicationData.setTitle(publicationName);

publicationData.setPublicationUrl(publicationName);

 publicationData.setKey(publicationName);

publicationData.setPublicationType("Web");

 publicationData.setPublicationPath(publicationName);

 System.out.println("in publication");

publicationData=(PublicationData)client.create(publicationData,new ReadOptions());
```

when i am creating publication by this code i am getting an exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServiceCreateCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage:
>   The transaction has aborted.

Comment: which version of Tridion are you using?

Comment: Sdl Tridion 2013

Comment: Does it take a long time to save when creating through the GUI?  Do you have hundreds or thousands of Publications?  You can increase the core service timeout in the config binding of your app.

Comment: Take a look at the event log on the server and there should be an event log with additional details and stack trace please share that.

Comment: Yes it take a long time to save when creating through the GUI and i am getting same error on GUI also

Answer (score 1):

you can try the code below, as you did not mention the version. this should work for 2011

```
       String publicationName="WebSite";

       PublicationData publicationData = new PublicationData() ;
       publicationData.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
       publicationData.Title = publicationName;
       publicationData.PublicationUrl = publicationName;
       publicationData.Key = publicationName;

        publicationData.PublicationType = "Web";

        publicationData.PublicationPath = publicationName;

        publicationData = (PublicationData)tridionClient.Create(publicationData, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: I think pankaj is using a Java client. This is a snippet for .NET.

Comment: @Likhan : well, I have not consumed core service in java application ever. How it is different using in java? or you are talking about the syntex?

Answer (score 1):

Set the publication ID property as well with `tcm:0-0-0` and this should resolve the issue.

Add below line as well in your code before you call the create method:

```
publicationData.setPublicationID("tcm:0-0-0");
```